# Opencart 3 получить данные из своей таблице в БД

Tags: php, mysqli, opencart, opencart3.x

Создал свою таблицу данных в бд (нужно для проекта) и пытаюсь вывести данные из нее в шаблон opencart 3.
Но twig не дает выполнить обычный PHP и комментирует все.
Подскажите как правильно это сделать!
В скрипте есть запрос в БД и получение из него данных.
Спасибо!

Comment: добавьте к вопросу шорт-листинг кода контроллера (как получали данные) и темплейта (как пытаетесь получить на фронт).

Comment: я сделал на тестовой странице просто, а вот как разбросать код по контроллерам и темплейткам я хз =(